# Should I always use the terminal for a portable program?

Tags: sqlite, portable

I got the portable version of SQLite Studio from the website https://sqlitestudio.pl/.

I am a new ubuntu user and wonder. Should I always go to the file location and run the executable file to launch the program?

I would like to pin this program on the panel and see the program icon. Is there a way to do this?

Currently, I am using this way on the terminal from my home directory;

```
cd SQLiteStudio
```

after to run,

```
./sqlitestudio
```

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04, Environment: KDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just right click on the sidebar icon after sqlitestudio is launched and select '*pin*' or '*add to favorites*'.
[image: steps to add as favorite]